# Table lock in Stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am using Stored Procedure which is returning 5-6 tables and this procedure may be in use simultaneous by many users (5-10 users) at same time.

Procedure has only "Select" statements.

So I just wanted to confirm is there any lock apply for the tables of Stored Procedure whenever the Procedure will call or there will be no lock.

I am using MS SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: yes lock applies on the table and its very basic concept you should know. if someone is inserting or updating the record table will be locked and unlocked. best way is to use select statement like this : select * from table with(nolock).... once data is inserted or updated lock will be removed automatically.

Comment: @Dirty, in my procedure I am using only "Select" statements". So do you means I have to change my query like this-

Select * from table with(nolock)

Comment: Don't use "with (nolock)"! It will allow your procedure to read rows which are currently being updated or even deleted by an ongoing transaction before they are committed (dirty reads).

Comment: @sunil, using nolock will give you one benefit that it won't lock out any data while others are updating or inserting new and drawback is you can have dirty read data. Like me, I always use nolock in my project because I provide priority Insert, Update and delete. It seems in your case you have to decide what your data contains? will dirty read data be allowed? Only drawback in your case there will be a lock by a user on the datatable and other users have to wait until lock is released.

Comment: @Dirty, thanks for your answer. I just wanted to ask whta is "Dirty read data" and will this apply for "Select" as well. Means If user "A" is using my procedure which has some "Select" statements and User "B","C"...etc are also using my procedure at the same time, so the procedure should not block/lock any table for "Selection" and also from "Insert,Update or Delete" operations.

Comment: It will lock based on the type. I think thegameiswar is provided enough information to start with. SQL is no simple as we think ! :) happy exploring!

Answer (score 1):

There will be [S (shared) locks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx):
"Used for read operations that do not change or update data, such as a SELECT statement." Note that an S-lock does not prevent other read operations.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any lock apply for the tables of Stored Procedure whenever the Procedure will call or there will be no lock.

select statement,will take shared locks.How long this lock will be taken depends on your isolation level

**Readcommitted:**  lock will be immediately released after reading row

**Repeatable read:** shared lock will be taken until the end of transaction,so  selected rows can not be modified

**serializable:** lock will be taken for the duration of transaction,new rows can't be added or old rows can't be modified as well

Comment: #TheGameiswar, If I dont use any Isolation level then ? Means I am simply using the select statement like this-

Select * from table

Or what happen if I use NOLock like this-

Select * from table (NoLock)

Comment: @sunil:when you use nolock ,it means you might have a chance of reading uncommitted data

Comment: @Sunil, the default isolation level is Read Committed. So if you are not specifying any isolation level, then you are using Read Committed.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, there is no need to consider about lock. Just take it easy. In the lock area, when many process was taken simultaneously, some of the process insert or update data.